# Fullscreen mode on video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I hope you can help.

Trying to make my video full screen but unable to.

Used MDN specifications and their code in order to help me.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTML Video Player</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

   <div class="player">
     <video class="player__video viewer" src="652333414.mp4"></video>

     <div class="player__controls">
       <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress__filled"></div>
       </div>
       <button class="player__button toggle" title="Toggle Play">►</button>
       <input type="range" name="volume" class="player__slider" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1">
       <input type="range" name="playbackRate" class="player__slider" min="0.5" max="2" step="0.1" value="1">
       <button data-skip="-10" class="player__button">« 10s</button>
       <button data-skip="25" class="player__button">25s »</button>
       <button type="button" data-state="go-fullscreen" class = "fullscreen__button">Fullscreen</button>
     </div>
   </div>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  background: #7A419B;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #7c1599 0%,#921099 48%,#7e4ae8 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.player {
  max-width: 750px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* This css is only applied when fullscreen is active. */
.player:fullscreen {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.player:-webkit-full-screen {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.player__video {
  width: 100%;
}

.player__button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.player__button:focus {
  border-color: #ffc600;
}

.player__slider {
  width: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.player__controls {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(100%) translateY(-5px);
  transition: all .3s;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.player:hover .player__controls {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.player:hover .progress {
  height: 15px;
}

.player__controls > * {
  flex: 1;
}

.progress {
  flex: 10;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

.progress__filled {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffc600;
  flex: 0;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

/* unholy css to style input type="range" */

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #ffc600;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -3.5px;
  box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #bada55;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #ffc600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
/* Get Our Elements */

const player = document.querySelector('.player');
const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');
const progress = player.querySelector('.progress');
const progressBar = player.querySelector('.progress__filled');
const toggle = player.querySelector('.toggle');
const skipButtons = player.querySelectorAll('[data-skip]');
const ranges = player.querySelectorAll('.player__slider');
const fullScreen = player.querySelector('.fullscreen__button');

/*Build our functions */


// Play and Pause video
function togglePlay(){
  if (video.paused){
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }
}

// Update Buttons when pausing
function updateButton(){
  const icon = this.paused ? '►' : '❚ ❚';
  toggle.textContent = icon;
}

// Update
function skip (){
  video.currentTime += parseFloat(this.dataset.skip);
}

function handleRangeUpdate(){
  video[this.name] = this.value;
}

function handleProgress(){
  const percent = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
  progressBar. style.flexBasis = `${percent}%`;
}

function scrub(e){
  const scrubTime = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
  video.currentTime = scrubTime;
}

function makeItBigger(){
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
     document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
 } else {
   if (document.exitFullscreen) {
     document.exitFullscreen();
   }
 }
}
/* Hook up event listenrs*/

video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
video.addEventListener('play', updateButton);
video.addEventListener('pause', updateButton);
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', handleProgress);
toggle.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
fullScreen.addEventListener('click', makeItBigger);

skipButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', skip));
ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('change', handleRangeUpdate));

let mousedown = false;
progress.addEventListener('click', scrub);
progress.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousedown && scrub(e));
progress.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mousedown = true);
progress.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mousedown = false);
```

The fullscreen is applied to the full window instead rather than just my video. I can see function is working just probably is not the right one.

I would like my actual video (black background) to be in fullscreen instead.

Comment: Well don’t call the method that requests fullscreen on the document root element then, but on the one you actually want to go fullscreen …?

Answer (score 0):

May be this would help you

```
.player:fullscreen {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; 
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```